# Spark- consecutive pipe delimiters being read as one

Tags: file, apache-spark, delimiter

I have a file with columns with empty rows like:

`1|2|abc||||random|12|||`

`1|2||||random|12|||151|`

Reading this in spark with the delimeter option set to |, the consecutive pipes are being read as one | and the data is getting shifted towards the left, or my insert is failing in certain cases.

I found the following relevant link, but nothing about spark.
https://kb.iu.edu/d/bcjf

How do I read a file like this correctly in spark?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are reading the file using `csv` format and specifying delimiter option as `"|"`.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.read.option("delimiter","|").format("csv").load("t.txt").show()
+---+---+----+----+----+------+------+----+----+----+----+
|_c0|_c1| _c2| _c3| _c4|   _c5|   _c6| _c7| _c8| _c9|_c10|
+---+---+----+----+----+------+------+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  2| abc|null|null|  null|random|  12|null|null|null|
|  1|  2|null|null|null|random|    12|null|null| 151|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+------+------+----+----+----+----+
```

It doesn't seems columns order is missing!